# How to store enum values in a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

My problem is since an enum in objective-c essentially is an int value, I am not able to store it in a `NSMutableArray`. Apparently `NSMutableArray` won't take any c-data types like an int.

Is there any common way to achieve this ?

```
typedef enum 
{
    green,
    blue,
    red

} MyColors;


NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             green,
                             blue,
                             red,
                             nil];

//Get enum value back out
MyColors greenColor = [list objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Wrap the enum value in an NSNumber before putting it in the array:

```
NSNumber *greenColor = [NSNumber numberWithInt:green];
NSNumber *redColor = [NSNumber numberWithInt:red];
NSNumber *blueColor = [NSNumber numberWithInt:blue];
NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             greenColor,
                             blueColor,
                             redColor,
                             nil];
```

And retrieve it like this:

`MyColors theGreenColor = [[list objectAtIndex:0] intValue];`

Comment: Generally this should be safe, but there are cases when it is not, since enums can be represented internally as a variety of different types.  See this answer for an alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187112/cocoa-dictionary-with-enum-keys/1187901#1187901

Answer (score 23):

A modern answer might look like:

```
NSMutableArray *list = 
 [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@(green), @(red), @(blue)]];
```

and:

```
MyColors theGreenColor = ((NSInteger*)list[0]).intValue;
```

Comment: MyColors theGreenColor = ((NSInteger*)list[0]).intValue;
Can be replaced by
MyColors theGreenColor = (MyColors)[list[0] intValue];

Answer (score 10):

Macatomy's answer is correct. But instead of NSNumber I would suggest you use NSValue. That is its purpose in life.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSMutableArray *corners = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                           @(Right), 
                           @(Top), 
                           @(Left), 
                           @(Bottom), nil];
Corner cornerType = [corner[0] intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your enum values in a NSNumber object:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:green];
```

Answer (score 0):

To go with `NSNumber` should be the right way normally. In some cases it can be useful to use them as `NSString` so in this case you could use this line of code:

```
[@(MyEnum) stringValue];
```