# How to store enum into Mutable Array in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

How can I store an enum in a mutable array in Swift please?

Below it is discussed for Objective-C and obviously it is working fine.
[How to store enum values in a NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487587/how-to-store-enum-values-in-a-nsmutablearray)

It is stored for int value using `array.addObject(0)`;

Comment: Please give us some code regarding the enum and how are you trying to use it in an array, the question is too broad otherwise

Comment: Why do you think you need to store it as an NSNumber?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
enum MyEnum {
    case Option1,
    Option2,
    Option3,
    Option4
}

var array: [MyEnum] = [.Option1, .Option2]
array.append(.Option3)
let b = MyEnum.Option4
array.append(b)

array[2] // Option3
```

If you want to store the enum values as integers, you can declare the enum as having the `rawValue` as an `Int` and use the `rawValue` property within the array:

```
enum MyEnum: Int {
    case Option1,
    Option2,
    Option3,
    Option4
}

var array: [Int] = [MyEnum.Option1.rawValue, MyEnum.Option2.rawValue]
array.append(MyEnum.Option3.rawValue)
let b = MyEnum.Option4
array.append(b.rawValue)

(array as NSArray).objectAtIndex(2) // a NSNumber with value 2
```

Comment: need to add it a s object type like store as NSNumber. This stores enum values

Comment: @GobiM I've updated my answer, please also update your question to reflect that you need to save NSNumber  value into the array

Comment: Thanks for your time! working, i hv done mistake for using rawValue :D

Answer (score 0):

Achieved as per @cristik answer

This solved my pblm,

let intervals: NSMutableArray = [Color.red.rawValue, Color.black.rawValue];